# Messaging apps don't receive messages when on WiFi with screen locked

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, whatsapp-messenger

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 phone running on Android 5.0. At home and in the office, when I'm connected to a WiFi network and the screen is locked (sleep), WhatsApp doesn't receive any messages until I unlock the screen. I don't use so many apps so I can't confirm if this is the case with other applications or not, however, I might have experienced the same problem with the email app as well.

I have observed my phone behavior and noted that other applications (e.g., hangouts) show act the same. Furthermore, I noted another fact that might shed some light: Say, I unlock my screen and after several seconds my apps start to notify me about some messages. But the time-stamp of these messages aren't for this moment but rather [e.g.] half an hour ago when they were supposed to be delivered.

"Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep" is set to "Always", I don't have any power management application or any particular settings. I checked WhatsApp FAQ and they suggested checking priority notification, which I don't use. Searching the web suggests clearing cache and data which doesn't solve the problem. I have cleared the cache/data files, updated the app, etc. I would highly applicate if you submit answers that do not suggest these generic (and almost always non-functional) workarounds.

Any workaround?

Comment: does it work when you are using cellular data instead of wi-fi?

Comment: @helleye, I can't be sure but I think it's a yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to the OS, as discussed in [Android Central forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/537843-notifications-not-working-when-screen-sleeping.html).

Maybe a new update from Samsung might fix this issue. You should contact Samsung service. Some guy exchanged his Samsung Galaxy S6 over this issue as mentioned in the discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Just uninstall WhatsApp and re-install again, but before doing so, you should backup all your files/conversations and it should work fine.

Also, it's better to power off the phone when you feel that you really don't need it especially during your night sleeping hours, or keep on Airplane Mode, it works.